# Best practice for database data rearrangement/transformation?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, data-transform

I have a MySQL database and retrieve data using php on a website where I would like to visualize the data in different ways. For this I also need to transform the data (e.g. creating sums, filtering etc.).

My question is now at which step of the data flow this kind of transformation makes most sense, especially regarding performance and flexibility. I am not a very experienced programmer, but I think these are the options I have:

1.) Prepare views in the database which are already providing the desired transformed data.

2.) Use a PHP script that SELECT's the data in the transformed way.

3.) Just have a `SELECT * FROM table` statement in PHP and load everything in a json, read it in js and transform the data to a desired version.

What is best practice to transform the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends in the architectural design of your application.

At this time SOA (Service Oriented Architecture) is a very used approach. If you use It, logic use to be in the services. Database is used as a data repository, and UI manage final data in light weight format, only really needed information.

So in this case, e.g. your option number 2 is most appropriated.

Comment: No. The answer lies somewhere between 2 and 3. So while it's sensible to aggregate and filter the data set in sql, pivoting the result into a table seems to me to be best handled in application code. And pagination can be handled in either, depending on the size of the result set.

Comment: Should I retrieve all the data at once (something like one single list of different transformed results in one single json) or should I have different php scripts each for one transformed data which are all retrieved separately in each location on the website?

Comment: I don't think a NO is friendly response to an answer that base it's content in a precondition. I mentioned SOA... And I stand with my opinion: in case of use SOA, most applicable option is the second.

Comment: @JoeBe that depends on the purpose of the service, and the real requirement of the UI.

Comment: @JoeBe that depends on the purpose of the service, and the real requirement of the UI. You can separate the requests if you see it worth because it makes your code more readable and/or gain modularity.

Comment: It is just a blog post where I want to display data in interactive charts.